# gatling Form Parameters : How to pass custom form-data to post request

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I am new to gatling scripting.  I am trying to execute a performance testing against one of our application's POST api. This POST request API required to pass the form-data.

EG : Print-Screen of the postman collection of the request body

[image]

For that I have prepared a gatling code piece as below :

```
      .exec(http("POST Explore JSON")
        .post("/sunrise/explore_json/")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .header("Referer", "https://example.com/sunrise/dashboard/dummy_dashboard/")
        .header("x-csrftoken", "${csrf_token1}")
        .queryParam("form_data","{\"slice_id\":4}")
      //.formParam("form_data","datasource":"2__table") ----------> Tried Method 1
      //.formParamSeq(Seq(("form_data", "datasource":"2__table")))  ----------> Tried Method 2
      //.formParamMap(Map("form_data" ->  "datasource":"2__table")) ----------> Tried Method 3
      //.form("""form_data={"datasource":"2__table"}""") ----------> Tried Method 4
```

Unfortunately gatling is not passing the form data as I want,currently how gatling pass the form data is :

`form_data: {"datasource":"2__table"}`

The way I want to pass is : (Please note I have removed the ":" & the following "space")

`form_data={"datasource":"2__table"}`

I have tried many many ways, but I could not successfully pass form data as above
Is there any way that I can pass as `form_data={"datasource":"2__table"}` ?

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that you're mixing request methods by sending a JSON object as form-data, typically this is how form data is sent (`key: value`). Can you check the console on your Postman to verify that it's being sent as `key=value`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 .formParam("form_data", "{\"datasource\":\"2__table\"}")
```

Comment: Can you explain - what can the OP expect after using this snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share, how we have fixed this issue,I guess it is another way representing form_data ?

```
    .exec(http("POST Explore JSON")
       .post("/sunrise/explore_json/")
       .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")   
       .header("Referer","https://example.com/sunrise/dashboard/dummy_dashboard/")
       .header("x-csrftoken", "${csrf_token1}")
       .queryParam("form_data","{\"slice_id\":4}")
       .bodyPart(StringBodyPart("form_data", s"""{"datasource":"2__table"}"""))
       .check(status.is(200))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same 'problem', you can try to use the *'.formParam'* after yours request.
For more information and examples look this: 
[Gatling Documentation: Form Parameters](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request#form-parameters)